# Can't seem to get modal to close on clicking "X"

Tags: javascript

Can't seem to get my modals to close on X. The first modal closes but the others do not. Thee below are snippet of code. Not the entirety. I can post the entirety if needed.

I have the window.onclick function working so if I click outside any modal it closes but the X only seems to work on the first modal I display. Any ideas?

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="startButton" class="button"></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <select id="selectMaterial"></select>

                    <div id="thickness">
                        <!-- <input id="enterThickness"> -->
                        <input id='enterThickness' class="input" type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1"
                            placeholder='Enter Material Thickness in Millimeters' /><span class="input-group-text"> /MM
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="rpm">
                        <!-- <input id="enterThickness"> -->
                        <input id='enterRPM' class="input" type="number" min="5000" max="60000" step="5000"
                            placeholder='Enter Max Spindle RPM' /><span class="input-group-text"> /RPM </span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="bitList">
                        <button id="bitsButton" class="button">SHOW AVAILABLE MILLING BITS</button>

                    </div>
                    <!-- <button id="calcButton" class="calcButton">CALCULATE CUTTING PARAMETERS</button> -->

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="myModal2" class="modal2">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <div id="displayInput"></div>
                    <select id="displayBits"></select>

                    <div id="selectBit">

                        <button id="selectBitsButton" class="button">SELECT BIT AND CALCULATE</button>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    <div id="myModal3" class="modal3">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>

            <div id="noBits">

                <button id="startOverButton" class="button">START OVER</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function (event) {

    if (event.target == modal || modal2 || modal3) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {

    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";

    }

    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";

    }

    if (event.target == modal3) {
        modal3.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Your first javascript line is only getting the first `span` even though you have three elements with that class `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]` so it only applies the click event to the first one.

Comment: I did try changing the class names as well. And renaming then doing an if statement for each of them. But didnt seem to work. document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0]; document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0]; document.getElementsByClassName("close3")[0];

Comment: @NikolaiMikkelsen try to create a code snippet like I just created in my answer using your code. It will help others understand and debug your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the name of the class, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of spans and `[0]` only selects the first item. You need to iterate over the list and apply the onclick to each one. Something like:

```
// Get all <span> elements that close the modal
var closeSpans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// convert list to an array and loop over each item
Array.from(closeSpans).forEach(function(span, idx, arr) {

    // now you can apply click to <span> like usual

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function (event) {

        if (event.target == modal || modal2 || modal3) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

});
```

Does that make sense? Otherwise, you would have to select each one separately by index like this (are you familiar with indexing?):

```
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
var span3 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
```

Comment: Makes sense, tried editing the code but still only working on the first modal. the idx and arr. what would I be applying to those?

Comment: `idx` give you the index number (0, 1, 2) of the current item, and `arr` is the original array that the item came from but you can probably ignore them for now unless you need them https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

You can also just write it as `Array.from(closeSpans).forEach(function(span)`

Comment: are you saying that I should iterate through the array? something like var span1 && var span2 && var span3 = ["close"];                                                                                       

                for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
                    var close = document.getElementByIdt('close');
                    }

Answer (score 0):

window.onClick event should be enough, you can use the id's of elements to identify them and set their styles

```js
// When the user clicks on the close spam, close the parent modal
window.onclick = function (event) {

    if (event.target.id == 'close1') {
        document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = "none";

    }

      if (event.target.id == 'close2') {
        document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";

    }
       if (event.target.id == 'close3') {
        document.getElementById('myModal3').style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="page">
            <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
            <button id="startButton" class="button"></button>

            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close" id="close1">&times;</span>
                    <select id="selectMaterial"></select>

                    <div id="thickness">
                        <!-- <input id="enterThickness"> -->
                        <input id='enterThickness' class="input" type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1"
                            placeholder='Enter Material Thickness in Millimeters' /><span class="input-group-text"> /MM
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="rpm">
                        <!-- <input id="enterThickness"> -->
                        <input id='enterRPM' class="input" type="number" min="5000" max="60000" step="5000"
                            placeholder='Enter Max Spindle RPM' /><span class="input-group-text"> /RPM </span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="bitList">
                        <button id="bitsButton" class="button">SHOW AVAILABLE MILLING BITS</button>

                    </div>
                    <!-- <button id="calcButton" class="calcButton">CALCULATE CUTTING PARAMETERS</button> -->

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="myModal2" class="modal2">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close" id="close2">&times;</span>
                    <div id="displayInput"></div>
                    <select id="displayBits"></select>

                    <div id="selectBit">

                        <button id="selectBitsButton" class="button">SELECT BIT AND CALCULATE</button>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    <div id="myModal3" class="modal3">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" id="close3">&times;</span>

            <div id="noBits">

                <button id="startOverButton" class="button">START OVER</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I definitely have something messed up. I pretty much copied your code from above but still cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I was able to trouble shoot it and find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dumping my full code in. Looks like it doesn't work here as well. So I have something that is a bit off. If I only insert the portions of the html and the script that I am working on it seems to work so something else I have is causing it to fail without errors.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal2");

var modal3 = document.getElementById("myModal3");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");

// // Get the <span> element that closes the modal

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
startButton.onclick = function() {
  enterThickness.value = null;
  enterRPM.value = null;
  selectMaterial.value = "Select Material";
  thickness.style.visibility = "hidden";
  rpm.style.visibility = "hidden";
  bitList.style.visibility = "hidden";
  modal.style.display = "block";
  displayBits.value = null;
  displayBits.value = "Select Bit";
  //startOverButton.style.visibility = "hidden",

}

var created = false;

var materialValue;

var thicknessValue;
var enteredThickness = document.getElementById(enterThickness);

var rpmValue;
var enteredRPM = document.getElementById(enterRPM);

var select = document.getElementById('selectMaterial');
var select2 = document.getElementById('displayBits');


var materials = [{
    name: "Select Material"
  },
  {
    name: "Acrylic",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  },
  {
    name: "Aluminum",
    metal: true,
    plastic: false,
    multipurpose: false,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  },
  {
    name: "Armed Graphite Gasket",
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  },
  {
    name: "Hard Brass",
    metal: true,
    plastic: false,
    multipurpose: false,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  },
  {
    name: "Hard Foam",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  },
  {
    name: "PVC - Soft",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: true,
    hard: false
  },
  {
    name: "PVC - Rigid",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  },
  {
    name: "Polycarbonate - Soft",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: true,
    hard: false
  },
  {
    name: "Polycarbonate - Rigid",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  },
  {
    name: "Polypropylene",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: true,
    hard: false
  },
  {
    name: "Wood - Soft",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: true,
    hard: false
  },
  {
    name: "Wood - Hard",
    metal: false,
    plastic: true,
    multipurpose: true,
    soft: false,
    hard: true
  }

];

var bits = [

  {
    name: 'M1-308U',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 3,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .005
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-308UC',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 3,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .005
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-408U',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .004,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-506D',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 6,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .005,
    hard: .007
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-506U',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 6,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 55000,
    soft: .005,
    hard: .007
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-506UC',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 6,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-608U',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-608UC',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'M1-608UC',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'M2-406U',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 6,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'M2-606U',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 6,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .005,
    hard: .007
  },
  {
    name: 'MZ-303U',
    material: 'metal',
    ced: 3,
    cel: 3,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .005
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-208D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 2,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .005
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-208U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 2,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .003,
    hard: .005
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-306U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 3,
    cel: 6,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .004,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-312D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 2,
    cel: 8,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .004,
    hard: .005
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-312U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 3,
    cel: 12,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .004,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-418D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 40000,
    soft: .005,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-418U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .005,
    hard: .007
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-518D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 40000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-518U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .009
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-613U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 13,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .012
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-613D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 13,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .012
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-625U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 25,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .012
  },
  {
    name: 'P1-625D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 25,
    flutes: 1,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .012
  },
  {
    name: 'P2-418D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .005,
    hard: .007
  },
  {
    name: 'P2-418U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .005,
    hard: .007
  },
  {
    name: 'P2-520D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 20,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'P2-520U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 20,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .009
  },
  {
    name: 'P2-613U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 13,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .012
  },
  {
    name: 'P2-625D',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 25,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .012
  },
  {
    name: 'P2-625U',
    material: 'plastic',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 25,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .012
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-418S',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'straight',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-420D',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 20,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-420U',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 20,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-520C',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 5,
    cel: 20,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'compression',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .004,
    hard: .006
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-625C',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 20,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'compression',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .010
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-418S',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 4,
    cel: 18,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'straight',
    rpm: 60000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .008
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-625D',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 25,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'down',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .010
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-625D',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 25,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'straight',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .006,
    hard: .009
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-625U',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 25,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'up',
    rpm: 50000,
    soft: .008,
    hard: .010
  },
  {
    name: 'X2-650U',
    material: 'multipurpose',
    ced: 6,
    cel: 50,
    flutes: 2,
    angle: 'straight',
    rpm: 40000,
    soft: .007,
    hard: .009
  },

];

window.onclick = function(event) {

  document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  window.onclick = function(event) {

    if (event.target.id == "close1") {
      document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";

    }

    if (event.target.id == "close2") {
      document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";

    }
    if (event.target.id == "close3") {
      document.getElementById('myModal3').style.display = "none";

    }
  }

  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";

  }

  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";

  }

  if (event.target == modal3) {
    modal3.style.display = "none";
  }

  if (!event.target.matches('.materialButton')) {

    if (!created) {
      for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = materials[i].name;
        opt.value = materials[i].name;
        select.appendChild(opt);
      }
      created = true;
    }

  }

  selectMaterial.addEventListener('change', function() {

    thickness.style.visibility = "hidden";
    rpm.style.visibility = "hidden";
    bitList.style.visibility = "hidden";

    if (this.value != "Select Material") {
      thickness.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

  });

  var thickness = document.getElementById("thickness");

  enterThickness.addEventListener('change', function() {

    thicknessValue = document.getElementById('enterThickness').value;

    rpm.style.visibility = "hidden";
    bitList.style.visibility = "hidden";

    if (thicknessValue > 50) {
      window.alert("Please enter a lower material thickness.");
    }

    if (materialValue != "Select Material") {
      rpm.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

  });

  var rpm = document.getElementById("rpm");

  enterRPM.addEventListener('change', function enteredRPM() {

    rpmValue = document.getElementById('enterRPM').value;

    bitList.style.visibility = "hidden";

    if (rpmValue > 60000 | rpmValue < 5000) {
      window.alert("Please enter spindle RPM between 5,000 and 60,000.");
    }

    if (rpmValue != null) {
      bitList.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

  });

  bitsButton.onclick = (function() {

    var userInputArray = new Array;

    materialValue = document.getElementById("selectMaterial").value;

    userInputArray = [materialValue, thicknessValue, rpmValue];

    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal2.style.display = "visible";
    modal2.style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById('displayInput').innerHTML = 'Compatible bits for' + " " + thicknessValue + " " + "mm" + " " + materialValue + " " +
      "at" + " " + rpmValue + " " + "RPM as follows;";

    var created2 = false;

    if (!created2) {

      const material = materials.find(item => item.name === materialValue);

      const selectedBits = bits.filter(bit =>
        (material.plastic && bit.material === 'plastic' && bit.cel >= thicknessValue) ||
        (material.metal && bit.material === 'metal' && bit.cel >= thicknessValue) ||
        (material.multipurpose && bit.material === 'multipurpose' && bit.cel >= thicknessValue)
      );

      if (selectedBits != undefined || selectedBits.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedBits.length; i++) {
          var opt = document.createElement('option');
          opt.innerHTML = selectedBits[i].name;
          opt.value = selectedBits[i].name;
          select2.appendChild(opt);
        }

        if (selectedBits === undefined || selectedBits.length == 0) {
          // array empty or does not exist
          modal2.style.display = "none";
          modal3.style.display = "visible";
          modal3.style.display = "block";
          noBits.style.visibility = 'visible';
          startOverButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
          created2 = false;
        };

      }

    }

    created2 = true;


  });

};
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Bits Blades Belts">
  <!--<meta name="keywords" content="VICOM-128, HTML Contact Form">-->
  <meta name="keywords" content="Zund, Esko, Kongsberg, MCT, Mikkelsen">
  <meta name="author" content="Nikolai Mikkelsen">
  <!--Meta data above-->
  <title>
    Bits Blades Belts
  </title>
  <!--Title-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
  <!--Link to style sheet-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header>
      <div class="img_header">
        <img src="images/headLogo.png" alt="HOME" />
        <h1 class="blink">YOUR TRUSTED CONSUMABLES PROVIDER</h1>
      </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="mobile_menu"></nav>
    <nav id="nav_menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html" title="Home">
            <img src="images/home.png" alt="HOME" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="lastItem">
          <a href="cnc_calculator.html">CNC CALCULATOR</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>

      <article class="marginUpper boxit">
        <h3>Welcome to the CNC Calculator</h3>
        <p>
          The CNC Calculator is the first step in developing a filtering system that will allow a customer to select a material and thickness of material to be processed. This will then provide a list of bits (products) that are compatible with the material and
          thickness. Once the material and thickness are determined and the bit selected, the calculator will then ask the user to enter the max RPM of the spindle. From there the application will calculate the feed rate, number of passes, and the RPM
          to process at.
        </p>

        <p>
          <br />Next semester the goal is to port this to PHP and expand on it the functionality to be able to filter by machine (manufacture), material group, sub-category, system tool options available, and will then recommend the milling or cutting
          tool and its feed rates, and if applicable, the number of passes and RPM.
        </p>
      </article>

      <article class="marginUpper boxit">
        <h3>Click Below To Select Start the CNC Calculator</h3>
      </article>

      <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
      <button id="startButton" class="button">OPEN CALCULATOR</button>

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" id="close1">&times;</span>
          <select id="selectMaterial"></select>

          <div id="thickness">
            <!-- <input id="enterThickness"> -->
            <input id='enterThickness' class="input" type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1" placeholder='Enter Material Thickness in Millimeters' /><span class="input-group-text"> /MM
                        </span>
          </div>

          <div id="rpm">
            <!-- <input id="enterThickness"> -->
            <input id='enterRPM' class="input" type="number" min="5000" max="60000" step="5000" placeholder='Enter Max Spindle RPM' /><span class="input-group-text"> /RPM </span>
          </div>

          <div id="bitList">
            <button id="bitsButton" class="button">SHOW AVAILABLE MILLING BITS</button>

          </div>
          <!-- <button id="calcButton" class="calcButton">CALCULATE CUTTING PARAMETERS</button> -->

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="myModal2" class="modal2">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" id="close2">&times;</span>
          <div id="displayInput"></div>
          <select id="displayBits"></select>

          <div id="selectBit">

            <button id="selectBitsButton" class="button">SELECT BIT AND CALCULATE</button>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div id="myModal3" class="modal3">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" id="close3">&times;</span>

          <div id="noBits">No router bits are available for this material and/or thickness.

            <button id="startOverButton" class="button">START OVER</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </main>

</body>

//
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!--Link to scripts-->

</html>
```

Comment: Figured it out. I am running all the modals within a long function that allows me to click outside of any modal to close. By moving the X to close function inside of this function it now works. Probably a messy way I did the code structure but I will clean it a bit more when I finish off the last of the code.